# Error installing MySQL-python on a windows 7 box

Tags: python, windows, mysql-python

I'm trying to install django on a windows machine (I swear, it's not my fault).
When it comes to the mysqldb module, I keep getting this error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\ME> easy_install MySQL-python
Searching for MySQL-python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
Downloading http://download.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/mysql-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\ME\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-bl367m\MySQL-python-1.2.3\egg-dist-tmp-wgpnqn
error: The system cannot find the file specified
```

What's the problem? I tried also downloading the sources and installing via python setup.py but the error persists (it's a bit different, tho):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\Users\samuele.mattiuzzo\Downloads\Django_python_apps\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install with the exe from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

I've been stuck there, done that etc..

Comment: thanks, it worked (sorry for slow reply, christmas holydays took most of my time)